# 3-way frequency table in R

Tags: r, frequency-analysis

I'm trying to code a three-way frequency table in R, but I'm stumbling due to the third variable. I want the table to look like this:

```
                            Lung Cancer
                            Yes      No
        City      Smoking
        Beijing     Yes     126      100
                    No      35       61
        Shanghai    Yes     908      688
                    No      497      807
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: look at `?ftable` eg `with(mtcars, ftable(cyl, am, vs))`

Comment: I would go with xtabs.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to use `by()`. For instance

```
by(data = my.data, INDICES = my.data$City, FUN = table, my.data$Smoking, my.data$LungCancer)
```

Answer (score 0):

**creating the data**

```
City <- c("Beijing", "Shanghai") 
Smoking <- c ("No", "Yes") 
LungCancer <- c("No", "Yes") 
health <- data.frame (City,Smoking, LungCancer)
```

**three way cross table**
I found this package

```
source("http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r")
crosstab(health, row.vars = c("City","Smoking"), col.vars = "LungCancer",addmargins = FALSE)
```

Hope this helps:-)